# Query to filter data enter some hours ago

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data base and I want to filter data by last updated time. I have last_updated_time in database ( name = uploads) as datetime.

I have SQL which can select data entered in within last 6 hrs. I want opposite one. I want to select data entered before 6 hrs.

```
SELECT `id`, `buyer_name`, `order_number`, `start_date`, `price`, `last_updated_date`, `state`,`admin_checked`,`account`, `designer`, `type`, `note`   
FROM uploads 
WHERE last_updated_date >= DATE_SUB(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'SYSTEM','+5:30'),INTERVAL 6 HOUR) 
ORDER BY state ASC , last_updated_date DESC
```

Comment: What's with all these conversions? Aren't you storing the time in UTC?

Comment: Ummm....    `last_updated_date <  something...` ?

Comment: yes it worked. reversing > to < worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

answer to question was reversing the `>` to `<`

```
SELECT `id`, `buyer_name`, `order_number`, `start_date`, `price`, `last_updated_date`, `state`,`admin_checked`,`account`, `designer`, `type`, `note`   
FROM uploads 
WHERE last_updated_date <= DATE_SUB(CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'SYSTEM','+5:30'),INTERVAL 6 HOUR) 
ORDER BY state ASC , last_updated_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `last_updated_date` is set on the same database where this is running, then you don't need to worry about timezones.  If that is the case, you can simply use:

```
WHERE last_updated_date < now() - interval 6 hour
```